# How to remotely set multiple calendar entries of an Outlook calendar?

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook, multiple-entries

We have a shared excel file at work that we use as our shift planning roster, I would like to make a C# application that would query the file and depending on a selection, it would somehow send several entries/events to that particular users's outlook calendar.

I haven't had too much luck searching for how to do this, could someone please point me in the right direction? I can figure out the excel part but I have no idea how to make that work seamlessly with Outlook.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Application.CreateItem to create entries in the user's default Calendar.  You can obtain their default Calendar by getting a Folder object reference from [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff866724.aspx).

See also: "[Create an Appointment as a Meeting on the Calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff861308.aspx)"